# How do I compile and run project on build for another project

Tags: visual-studio, build, msbuild-task

I have two projects. One project is preparing a json data file for the other project.

What I want to do now is when I compile Project A, I want it to compile and run Project B. Because Project B will generate a file which gets added to the output of Project A.

Is it possible to do this with Visual Studio build events? If so how can I achive this?